Callback for monitoring the creating of files/folder and the changes in the files in Cloud Files API
In Cloud Files API, the platform invokes the respective callback function for the callback types.
there is a callback type for everything - reading, moving, deleting, renaming, list fetching - but I am not able to find any callbacks for monitoring the creation of files and folders under the sync root.
I noticed the CfConvertToPlaceholder to convert the normal file/directory to a placeholder file, but how does the app know, or the OS tell the app, that a new file/folder has been created?
How can we accomplish this using the Cloud Files API?

No, this is not the purpose the CfAPI (it just handles the placeholder concept, it's very var from being a "sync engine" as advertised somehow, it's brings support for building one), you must do this yourself as demonstrated in the CloudMirror sample https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/CloudMirror/CloudMirror/CloudProviderSyncRootWatcher.cpp#L72 using ReadDirectoryChangesW or ReadDirectoryChangesExW APIs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw

As Simon mentioned in the comment, the CfApi is incomplete in this regard (probably, Microsoft did plan to make the corresponding callbacks, but they never finished this part). You need to employ external means for monitoring of the changes that occur within the synchronization root. This can be the ReadDirectoryChangesW() Windows API function or a filesystem filter driver. The WinAPI function is simpler, but not without quirks. The driver approach is more reliable, and to a certain extent removes the need for CfApi. For example, our CBFS Filter product has a relatively small Placeholder sample that does basically all the non-visual stuff that CfApi offers. The only benefit of CfApi is Explorer integration - the sync.root becomes a part of the namespace and is visible separately (including a custom column for a hydration status). The UI part is not something we aimed to replicate within the sample (although this is possible as well using our CBFS Shell product).
One more thing to take into account - CfApi does notify you about renames and deletes, but while working on the CBFS Sync product, we have discovered that "thanks but no thanks" - we better track renames and deletes on our own based on the monitoring results. The notifications that CfApi sends had some big problems with multithreading and something else (I don't remember the details already).
